# How to check a instance of a template code

Tags: c++, compilation

I write a template class in c++ like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    T t;
}
```

When I instantiate A like this:

```
A<int> a;
```

Then how can I confirm that the compiler will generate code like below as I expected:

```
class A {
    int t;
}
```

How to check this?

Comment: Why do you need to check this?  Do you suspect the compiler is doing something wrong?  You might be able to see it in a intermediary file.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The compilers are all right, be sure, unless you're using some archaic compiler.

Comment: @ForceBru, sometimes I need to verify if the compiler generate code as I expected when using template, especially when it's a template method.So do you have any suggestions? As for intermediary, where to find or how to generate manually.